# Could not load Sharepoint.Client.dll in the application installed machine

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-addin

I have build an add-in for share-point and wrapped it with `wix setup`. In my application I have referenced for `SharePoint.Client.dll`.

But when ever I tried to open my application (`installed in other machine`) it throws me an error as could not load assembly.

[image]

> **NOTE**: My application installed machine doesn't have SharePoint installed.

What is the problem? I have build the `setup` using `wix`.
But everything works perfectly on development environment and there i have sharepoint installed.

Comment: how do add this dll into your solution?

Comment: just by clicking 'Add Reference' in visual studio under .Net tab @AtishDipongkor

Comment: That means you give it from GAC. Add a folder in your solution ... paste the dll into it and add reference from this folder.

Comment: @AtishDipongkor in developer environment uh..?

Comment: Yes ...... In your vs solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works on your DEV, bacause you have SharePoint Client DLLs installed. If you want to install your solution on other server, you need to copy those dlls to your BIN folder.

In *Solution Explorer* right click referenced DLLs (`Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll`, `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll`) and select *Properties*. Set *Copy Local* to `True`.